# Accessing Pandas groupby() function

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have the below data frame with me after doing the following:

```
train_X = icon[['property', 'room', 'date', 'month', 'amount']]
train_frame = train_X.groupby(['property', 'month', 'date', 'room']).median()
print(train_frame)
```

---

```
                          amount
property month date room          
1        6     6    2     3195.000
               12   3     2977.000
               18   2     3195.000
               24   3     3581.000
               36   2     3146.000
                    3     3321.500
               42   2     3096.000
                    3     3580.000
               54   2     3195.000
                    3     3580.000
               60   2     3000.000
               66   3     3810.000
               78   2     3000.000
               84   2     3461.320
                    3     2872.800
               90   2     3461.320
                    3     3580.000
               96   2     3534.000
                    3     2872.800
               102  3     3581.000
               108  3     3580.000
               114  2     3195.000
```

---

My objective is to track the median amount based on the (property, month, date, room)
I did this:

```
big_list = [[property, month, date, room], ...]
test_list = [property, month, date, room]

if test_list == big_list:
    #I want to get the median amount wrt to that row which matches the test_list
```

How do I do this?

What I did is, tried the below...

```
count = 0
test_list = [2, 6, 36, 2]

for j in big_list:
    if test_list == j:
        break

    count += 1
```

Now, after getting the count how do I access the median amount by count in dataframe? Is their a way to access dataframe by index?

Please note:

1. big_list is the list of lists where each list is [property, month, date, room] from the above dataframe
2. test_list is an incoming list to be matched with the big_list in case it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the last question:
*Is their a way to access dataframe by index?*

Of course there is - you should use df.iloc or loc
depends if you want to get purerly by integer (I guess this is the situation) - you should use 'iloc' or by for example string type index - then you can use loc.

Documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Edit:
Coming back to the question. 
I assume that 'amount' is your searched median, then.
You can use reset_index() method on grouped dataframe, like

```
train_frame_reset = train_frame.reset_index()
```

and then you can again access your column names, so you should be albe to do the following (assuming j is index of found row):

```
train_frame_reset.iloc[j]['amount'] <- will give you median
```

Comment: price = train_frame.iloc[count];
price = price[0]; 
this resolved the purpose

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you don't need to count at all, you can access the values via loc directly.

Look at:

```
A=pd.DataFrame([[5,6,9],[5,7,10],[6,3,11],[6,5,12]],columns=(['lev0','lev1','val']))
```

Then you did:

```
test=A.groupby(['lev0','lev1']).median()
```

Accessing, say, the median to the group lev0=6 and lev1 =1 can be done via:

```
test.loc[6,5]
```